# Beautifull soup install mac error

Tags: java, python, macos, beautifulsoup

I am getting the following error message when i try to install Beautifullsoup via mac terminal.

[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/test-easy-install-40423.pth'

Please help.

Comment: Prepend `sudo`?

Comment: This is not a question about programming, and is thus off-topic for Stack Overflow.  Perhaps [Super User](https://superuser.com/) is a better place for this question?

Comment: Welcome to SO! In order to receive better answers, I'd suggest that you provide what exact steps you've taken and that you explain what your exact goal is.

Answer (score 1):

In linux you can use the sudo command to bypass any permission issues, I believe that same can be said for mac os. Just add into your terminal `sudo "command"` this will basically install it as "super user" hence you shouldn't have an issue reading and writing to files at certain locations.

Comment: The recommended way is to use per-project virtualenvs to avoid messing with OS-level packages. Another alternative might be pip‘s ˋ--userˋ flag.